# Aligning image on right side of title on UIButton with imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I would like to add an image on the right side of the title something like this

```
|Button  [image]|
|title          |
```

And I am able to achieve this by this code

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0)
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 135, 0, 5)
```

But when the title is large, the title label and image intersect with each other.
How can I break the title label?

Comment: check the answer. it will never intersect title with image.

Answer (score 6):

This extension works for me:

Extension:

```
extension UIButton {
  func imageToRight() {
      transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
      titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
      imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
button.imageToRight()
```

[image]

**Update for iOS 15**

as described here: [Meet the UIKit Button System](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10064/)

1. Create your button configuration
   Choose from .plain(), .gray(), .tinted() or .filled()

   var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
2. Choose the placement for your image
   Choose from all, top, bottom, trailing, leading, none

   config.imagePlacement = .trailing
3. Assign the configuration to your button

   let myButton = UIButton(configuration: config, primaryAction: ...)

Comment: Yes, it does. The extension shown above works as intended. Puts the image to the right of the button title.

Answer (score 3):

try this, it will never intersect title and image with each other. and i created a button in storyboard in centre.
`@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!`

```
  let somespace: CGFloat = 10

  self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

  self.myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, self.myButton.frame.size.width - somespace , 0, 0)

  print(self.myButton.imageView?.frame)

  self.myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (self.myButton.imageView?.frame.width)! + somespace, 0, 10 )
```

[image]

and if you want multiline title for button change line break mode for button's title

```
self.myButton.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

[image]

**Swift 3.0**

In swift 3.0 you can easily do it in interface builder.

Select the UIButton -> Attributes Inspector -> go to size inspector and modify the image or title insets. and if you want image on button's right side simply select the  force `Right-to-left` in semantic view utilities

[image].

Comment: Hey, just a quick comment that actually using the semantic content attribute for this is not a good idea. It messes up with accessibility, especially with VoiceOver. If you are doing swipes to the right to navigate to the next element, and you get to a button that is forced to .forceRightToLeft, another swipe to the right will actually reverse VoiceOver's navigation, and will move the focus back to the previous element. If you swipe right again, you are back on the button that is forced right-to-left, and so on. So the user gets basically stuck in a focus trap, and it can be quite confusing.

Comment: That's true. It's just a hack. If anyone is using accessibility and supporting multiple languages in their project shouldn't use this.