# Get frame of the title Label inside the UIButton swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to create a UIButton that contains a UIImage and text. So far I have managed to do that but I can't make it look pretty because the button width is half of the screen size (and this means the proportions are not right on big screens when I set the image)

Is there a way to position the Image exactly before the text Label in the button? Now I am doing this:

```
 economicsButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15,left: 10,bottom: 15,right: 30)
 economicsButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
```

Comment: What does "position the image exactly before the text label" mean?

Comment: well I want the text to be centered in the button and the image to be right before the place where the text starts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
  let somespace: CGFloat = 10

  self.economicsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

 self.economicsButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, self.economicsButton.frame.size.width - somespace , 0, 0)

 print(self.economicsButton.imageView?.frame)

self.economicsButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,(self.economicsButton.imageView?.frame.width)! + somespace, 0, 10 )
```

[image]

check the original answer [Align image on right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020930/aligning-image-on-right-side-of-title-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-title/37023212#37023212)